# What do the trolls look like in The Hobbit?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-hobbit

In the book The Hobbit, Tolkien never says what the trolls look like. So by the way they talk and what is said about them, what do they look like?

Comment: Like this: https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/f2/d2/a7/f2d2a7f8fb770670b509dc2cb5f50a36.jpg